# Implementing transport over a graph

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, linked-list

I have a task at hand in which I have to lay down a rail time table, Now the rail track is straight and I have implemented a Doubly Linked List for the representation of a train terminal, a terminal behind this and a terminal ahead this are represented by the links in the list.

Now I want to implement a train over the tracks laid so far, I am not intrested in implementing a database and all my raw data is in the form of JSON. An example of one terminal in JSON looks like:

```
{
    "stations_array": [{
            "vertexId": 0,
            "name": "Terminal0",
            "lat": "84.2207",
            "lng": "74.3884",
            "isEndTerminal": true,
            "isFunctional": true,
            "vertNext": 1,
            "vertPrev": null
        },
        {
            "vertexId": 1,
            "name": "Terminal1",
            "lat": "104.2580",
            "lng": "94.4512",
            "isEndTerminal": false,
            "isFunctional": true,
            "vertNext": 2,
            "vertPrev": 1
        },
        {
            "vertexId": 2,
            "name": "Terminal2",
            "lat": "14.1659",
            "lng": "04.5632",
            "isEndTerminal": false,
            "isFunctional": true,
            "vertNext": 3,
            "vertPrev": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

And I represent a train in JSON as well, which is as below:

```
{
    "trains_array": [{
        "id": 16,
        "source": "Terminal0",
        "destination": "Terminal2",
        "start_time": "06:00",
        "days": "daily",
        "terminals": [{
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Terminal0",
                "time": "06:00"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "terminal1",
                "time": "06:12"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Terminal2",
                "time": "06:25"
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

Now the terminals array in the above JSON tells me where the train stops (id being the representation of a foreign key inside the terminal array for each object) and I calculate through code to know which train arrives at what time at which station, which station it stops or omits at. however this whole approach seems a bit hardcoded. I want to know if there is a better way I can represent things here.

Comment: So the stations will never have a fork? A station will always have just one previous and next stop?

Comment: Not in the current setup, I am mapping almost a straight rail link with double edges. Although I am not averse to a more broader solution which includes a fork!!

Comment: This is good but probably a very broad question. Open for a lot of interpretations. At the same time, there are a lot of existing solutions. You can take inspiration from > https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/
Short answer to `Is there a better way I can represent things here.` is `Yes.` :) Hope that helps.

Comment: @ajc Thanks, I will take a look there :)

Comment: The question is rather broad, what is it exactly that does not feel right for you in your approach? In any case, I think I'd represent things as a graph (e.g. [like this](http://netflix.github.io/falcor/documentation/jsongraph.html)), you could store link times/distances in the file or calculate them after creating the graph. I think I'd only store the list of stopping terminals in the trains document (not even sure about storing the name, since it's duplicated)... then you can compute the actual path (possibly with intermediate stations) from the graph, which maybe could change independently.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks, I will take a look there!

Comment: Also whoever has downvoted, please care to leave a comment about what you feel is not right about the question. Maybe that helps me improve it.

Comment: I think you're not getting much help because a large part of "what's an appropriate way to represent this?" is answered by "what purposes will you use it for?".  Representing it as a graph would be somewhat general, no-one has separated out the stations (vertices) from the tracks between them (edges) to get a truly general graph representation (i.e., where there can be 2+ different routes between a given pair of stations.  Also, why lat/long?  are you assuming your trains travel in straight lines over a perfectly spherical earth?  Why not put lengths on the edges that connect stations?

Comment: Not to kick a dead horse, but can two tracks only merge or fork at a station?  Maybe you need arbitrary vertices like "Crossover" or "Roundhouse".  In that sense, you may end with n track segments (edges) and n-1 vertices representing a single path between a given pair of stations.

Answer (score 2):

As the title suggested **Implementing transport over a graph** you should use a graph to represent the rail network. As all rails are bidirectional, I suppose, using a Doubly linked list does not make a lot of sense.

A list with the adjacent stations should be enough, simpler and more scalable, and you could use forks then.

```
{
    "stations_array": [{
            "vertexId": 0,
            "name": "Terminal0",
            "lat": "84.2207",
            "lng": "74.3884",
            "isEndTerminal": true,
            "isFunctional": true,
            "adj": [{1}]
        },
        {
            "vertexId": 1,
            "name": "Terminal1",
            "lat": "104.2580",
            "lng": "94.4512",
            "isEndTerminal": false,
            "isFunctional": true,
             "adj": [{0,2}]
        },
        {
            "vertexId": 2,
            "name": "Terminal2",
            "lat": "14.1659",
            "lng": "04.5632",
            "isEndTerminal": false,
            "isFunctional": true,
            "adj": [{1,3}]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A LinkedList is also a flavour of graph. Thanks I take the idea of Adjacent, which however translates to the edges in the LinkedList. Also its not necessary that a station with two adjacent stations cant be an end terminal

Comment: Say a Train moves only from B to D even when stations A through E exist.

Comment: You are right about the end terminal, better keep the attribute xD. But even if the linked list is a subset of a graph, the vertex degree is limited to only 2.

Comment: @User3 `isEndTerminal` still looks redundant to me. Even in the scenario where a train moves only on a segment of the entire route, `isEndTerminal` would be an attribute of a train, not a station. In fact, if you need to support "short routes", just a `isEndTerminal` flag would not be enough anyway.